# Simple exploit leads to wrong EIP and EBP

Tags: exploit

I have a simple program:

```
void bug(char *arg1)
{
    char name[128];
    strcpy(name, arg1);
    printf("Hello %s\n", name);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s <your name>\n", argv[0]);
        return 0;
    }

    bug(argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Machine: `Ubuntu 14.04.1 32-Bit / gcc version 4.8.2`

The file compiled with `-fno-stack-protector` and ALSR is off

This is what I get after try to execute it from gdb:

[image: Screenshot of output]

What I expected is to see the EIP set to `0x43434343` and EBP set to `0x42424242` but we see that they both are `0x41414141`

Please help. What was wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You just discover that GCC perform alignments on local variables (stack). An paper that could give you an idea of this concept is the following one: [Optimal Stack Slot Assignment in GCC](ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/summit/2003/Optimal%20Stack%20Slot%20Assignment.pdf)

Comment: On my opinion, your answer is excellent. Maybe it could be more better if you detailed a little bit more of the essence of the referred link.